# "PROCEDURE does not exist" thrown when calling existing procedure from shell script

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell, stored-procedures

I'm currently working on automating a process that exports MySQL data to a tab-delimited file and that dynamically ascertains the list of fields needing to be output. I've surmounted a number of hurdles, but now I'm stuck on something even after searching SO, Google, etc.

Specifically, I have a stored procedure that exists and is working exactly as intended when it is run from a mysql prompt; however, when I attempt to call the same stored procedure from a shell script I get the error `PROCEDURE schemaName.procedureName does not exist.`

For reference, here is the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 4 ]; then
    echo $'\nPlease include the following arguments:'
    echo $'\t- source schema name (aka, database name in MySQL)'
    echo $'\t- source data table name'
    echo $'\t- source database environment (prod, qa, or dev)'
    echo $'\t- database username\n'
    echo $'The arguments must be entered in that order.\n'
    echo $'Do not include the path for the destination filename. It will be saved to ~/csv-files/<table name>.'
    exit
fi

[[ -d ~/csv-files ]] || mkdir ~/csv-files
cols=$(echo "call $1.tab_delim_col_names('$2',@colNames)" | source ~/bin/$3_db_login $4)
echo "select concat($cols) from $1.$2" | source ~/bin/$3_db_login $4 > ~/csv-files/$1.$2.csv
```

And, here is the stored procedure:

```
delimiter //
create procedure tab_delim_col_names(
    IN tableName VARCHAR(100), 
    OUT columnList VARCHAR(1000)
)

begin
    declare n int default 0;
    declare i int default 0;
    declare colNames varchar(1000);

    select count(*) into @getCount
    from information_schema.columns 
    where table_name = tableName;

    set n = @getCount;
    set i = 0;

    while i < n do
        select column_name into @thisCol
        from information_schema.columns 
        where table_name = tableName
        limit i,1;

        if i > 0 then
            set colNames = concat(colNames, ',\'\\t\',', @thisCol);
        else
            set colNames = @thisCol;
        end if;

        set i = i + 1;
    end while;
    select colNames;
end;//
delimiter ;
```

As mentioned above, everything works perfectly when I execute this from a mysql prompt (without having selected a db):
    `call services.tab_delim_col_names('tableName',@colNames);`

But, I get the "PROCEDURE does not exist" error when the bash script executes this line:
    `cols=$(echo "call $1.tab_delim_col_names('$2',@colNames)" | source ~/bin/$3_db_login $4)`

I've tried hard coding $1 and $2 and it still didn't work, so the problem isn't bad args being passed in.

Any help is much appreciated!

P.S. - I'm also concerned that `select colNames` at the end of the procedure won't store a value in $cols that can be used successfully as a concat() argument, but I can't determine that until this issue is resolved.

Comment: How are you passing the arguments to the script? Can you show us the invocation?

Comment: Sure. The shell script is called "export_data" and it's stored in /bin, so I just execute the following from the standard prompt: export_data schema_name table_name env username

Comment: What is `@colNames` here? Is it supposed to expanded to a value?

Comment: `colNames` holds a value like `id, '\t', name, '\t', description`, which in turn I'd like to use for `select concat($cols) from schema.table` in the shell script. The thought is that this would be expanded to `select concat(id, '\t', name, '\t', description) from schema.table`